# Inserting multi-line text (paragraphs) in SQL using SQLite3

Tags: sql, string, sqlite, sql-insert

So I have this piece of code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS news(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    userid INTEGER,
    title TEXT NOT NULL,
    photo TEXT,
    datePosted DATE NOT NULL,
    article TEXT NOT NULL, 
    FOREIGN KEY(usersid) REFERENCES users(id)
);
```

And I am supposed to insert some information but the article field should contain a multi-line text.
And I'll use nodeJS and javascript(it's a crud app...) to extract this key and display it as a multi-line text.

So how should this be done in particular with the article field?

Something like below?

```
INSERT INTO news(userid, title, photo, datePosted, article)
VALUES(1, "...", "...", "...", "paragraph1" + CHAR(13) + "paragraph2")
```

Answer (score 0):

SQLite does not support `+` for string concatenation - this is bespoke SQL Server syntax. Using `+` forces the conversion of operands to numbers, and you get `'0'` as a result.

Instead, you can use standard string concatenation operator `||`, which SQLite understands:

```
INSERT INTO news(userid, title, photo, datePosted, article)
VALUES(1, '...', '...', '...', 'paragraph1' || CHAR(13) || 'paragraph2');
```

Note that I changed the double quotes to single quotes: the latter should always be preferred for literal strings (this also is SQL standard).